# How do I apply a set of keystrokes to every occurrence of a word?

Tags: search, macro

If I want to delete every word, that is easy, because I would do something like this:

```
:s%/WORD//g
```

But what if I want to do `xyz` to every occurrence of "WORD"? For example, let's say I want to delete every line that contains "WORD". I can think of a couple ways to do this, but none of them seem ideal.

1)

```
/WORD
```

and then manually press `ddnddnddnddn...` until there are no more occurrences. But this is time consuming if there are many lines to do this on.

2)

```
qd/WORD<enter>ddq
```

and then guess how many times WORD occurs, and then, for example:

```
500@d
```

But this will either A) miss a bunch of lines or B) delete of bunch of extra lines.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Just so you know, `500@d` as you describe is actually safe.  The macro playback will stop once the search term is not found.  So you'll just see an error "Pattern not found: WORD" after all lines containing it have been deleted.

Comment: @Wildcard Thankyou, that is really good to know!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the `:global` and `:normal` commands for this.  The `:global` command has the following syntax:

```
:global/{pattern}/{command}
```

This will run "command" on every occurrence of "pattern".  You can then use the `:normal` command to run a series of keystrokes on each occurrence of a word using `:global`.  Like so:

```
:g/WORD/normal {keystrokes}
```

If those keystrokes involve special keys like `<Ctrl>`, you can combine it with the `:execute` command like so:

```
:g/WORD/exe "normal {keystrokes}"
```

Do note that you must put a backslash before each occurrence of a special key.

For more on these commands, see `:help :normal` and `:help :global`.

Comment: Beat me to it; I guess I was typing too slow.  :)

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness, you *can*  use `:substitute`, if you match - in your example (delete the whole line that has WORD) - *the entire line* containing WORD, e.g.:

```
:%s/^.*\<WORD\>.*\n
```

This has an implicit "replace match with nothing", i.e. it's the shorter form of:

```
:%s/^.*\<WORD\>.*\n//
```

Combined with `\zs`, `\ze`, `\(`-`\)` (grouping), and `\=` (in the replacement part) with `submatch()`, `:substitute` can be very powerful.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are looking for `:global`.

```
:g/WORD/d_
```

Comment: What does the underscore do?

Comment: This works, but none of the commands I know work. I keep getting "not an editor command".

Comment: @Wildcard: The underscore discards what is being cut. The command executed is actually `:delete` and not the normal mode operation `d`.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem: for other normal operations, you'll need `:normal`. And if you need special keys, you may even need `:exe` -> `exe "normal aFooFar\<esc>"