# How do I comment out lines without changing indentation?

Tags: vimscript, indentation, comments

I use Vim to write my Python source and use the debugging library `pdb`.

Let's say I have this code with break points commented out:

```
import pdb

#pdb.set_trace()

def func1():
    #pdb.set_trace()
    foo_bar
```

I then want to globally un-comment all the `pdb.set_trace()` commands.
Also, I'll want to re-comment them.

I figured out how to search for the commented string:

```
^\(\s*#\)\@!\s*pdb.set_trace()
```

After this I don't know how to build a string of commands that would globally find the string and add a `#` to the beginning of the string so as not to mess up the indentation.

UPDATE:

I realized that I need to not re-comment lines with an existing `#` so I
built upon the accepted answer:

To comment out:

```
:g/\s*\(#\)\@<!pdb.set_trace()/normal I#
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alternatively, you could use the `:g` command. I would do:

```
:g/\s*#pdb.set_trace()/normal ^x
```

to uncomment and

```
:g/\s*pdb.set_trace()/normal I#
```

to comment. This is nice because it's more readable (and shorter) than a search and replace command. Explanation:

```
:g/\s*#pdb.set_trace()/             "For every line matching this regex
                       normal       "Execute the following normal mode keystrokes:
                               ^x   "Go to first non-whitespace character and delete it.
```

The recommenting works the same, except it searches for a different string, and it uses `I#` instead of `^x`. `I#` means insert `#` at the first non-whitespace column.

Comment: This is what I was originally thinking...will try now. :g command...need to utilize more than just :gQ

Comment: @wbg Glad I could help! For more reading on the `:g` command, see an old question of mine: http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/5091/2920

Comment: This works well for me. Other answers are good as well however I'm choosing this one because it worked without tinkering, and is easily grokked.

Answer (score 5):

There is a solution which can be pretty simple if you are willing to use a plugin: [NERDCommenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter).

This plugin is made for "intensely orgasmic commenting" according to their github page. More precisely it creates several mappings to handle comments and one of the mappings is `<Leader>ci` which allows to toggle the comments of a line.

Combined to a global command it allows you do to what you can. Let's say your leader is `,` is can use the following command:

```
:g/pdb.set_trace()/normal ,ci
```

And that will toggle the comments on the lines matching `pdb.set_trace()`

Note that you cannot easily use `<leader>`directly in the normal command (see [my question about that](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7779/1841))

If your leader is `<space>` you'll have to do:

```
:g/pdb.Set_trace()/normal 1 ci
```

Note that it is easy to map it to a key:

```
nnoremap <key> :g/pdb.set_trace()/normal ,ci<CR>
```

And finally the big advantage of this method is that NERDcommenter handles automatically the language you are editing so you can create a command which will togle the comments on lines matching a defined pattern no matter what language you're editing:

```
command! -nargs=1 ToggleCom :execute "g/" . <f-args> . "/normal ,ci"
```

Now no matter which language you're editing you can use `:ToogleCom foo` to toggle the comment of all the lines matching `foo`. (If your leader is not `,` see the previous paragraph of my answer)

If you need different commenting styles you can change the mapping used, see [`:h NERDComFunctionalitySummary`](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter/blob/master/doc/NERD_commenter.txt#L81) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do a search and replace.

```
:%s/^\(\s*\)#\(\s*pdb.set_trace()\)/\1\2/
```

To un-comment and

```
:%s/^\(\s*\)\(pdb.set_trace()\)/\1#\2/
```

To re-comment.

This is done by using back-references. Anything matched in between memory parentheses `\(\)` can be recalled by using a back-reference (`\1` and `\2` in this case).

Edit: Oh, and I kind of forgot that you said you wanted this in a script. For using this in a script just omit the first colon. :)

Here's an example of using it in a function:

```
function! UncommentSetTrace()
   %s/^\(\s*\)#\(\s*pdb.set_trace()\)/\1\2/
endfunction

function! CommentSetTrace()
   %s/^\(\s*\)\(pdb.set_trace()\)/\1#\2/
endfunction
```

You should be able to just call this function and it will comment/uncomment all instances in your current file. If you want to use a single keystroke you can map it to the function:

```
noremap <A-c> :call CommentSetTrace()<CR>
```

This maps <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to comment all the instances.

Comment: That makes sense...like sed, I'll try it now.

Comment: Having an issue with the match...I'll need to step away for a bit but will come back to this.

Comment: I like this idea but having trouble getting it working.