# How to use <Leader> in a normal command?

Tags: vimscript, key-bindings

In the command-line mode or in a vimscript I can use the following to duplicate a line:

```
normal! Yp
```

Now let's says that I map my leader key to do that: `nnoremap <Leader>a Yp`. If I use this key combination the following command will interpret litterally the characters or `<leader>`:

```
normal! <Leader>a
```

**How can I use a key combination including `<leader>` in a normal command?**

Note that other keys like `<Right>` or `<F3>` doesn't work neither.

**Edit** Some side notes:

- Using `normal` or `normal!` doesn't seem to change something to the problem
- The point of the question is to be able to use `<Leader>` and not replace it by its value for two 2 reasons:

  - It is more portable if I use it in a script and want to distribute it.
  - My leader is `<Space>` so even if I replace `<Leader>` by its value I still have the same problem. (Note that I could maybe escape a space character but that is not the point of the question)

Comment: Since you want your map to be used, you will need `normal` instead of `normal!`. My leader is `\​`, and I can use `normal \a` to execute the mapping, but I don't know how to keep it generic wrt leader.

Comment: @PhilippFrank: Thanks for your comment, please see my update: Replacing `<leader>` by its value is not really what I'm looking for.

Comment: Do you mind using and external command/function for this?

Comment: @Nobe4: I'd like a solution as straightforward as possible but if it is the only solution that will be ok :-)

Answer (score 7):

I made up a solution to extract the leader, handle the special `<space>` case and execute the normal command.

The space is a special case, because the `normal` command does not accept expressions starting with a space:

```
:h normal

{commands} cannot start with a space.  Put a count of
1 (one) before it, "1 " is one space.
```

Here is the function and command:

```
function! ExecuteLeader(suffix)
  let l:leader = get(g:,"mapleader","\\")

  if l:leader == ' '
    let l:leader = '1' . l:leader
  endif

  execute "normal ".l:leader.a:suffix
endfunction

command! -nargs=1 NormLead call ExecuteLeader(<f-args>)
```

You can use it this way:

```
:NormLead a
-> will execute `normal <leader>a`
```

---

(Thanks @statox for the update):
If you want a one-liner command, without function, you can use the following:

```
command! -nargs=1 NormLead  let leader=get(g:,"mapleader","\\") | exec "normal " . (leader==' '?"1":leader).<f-args>
```

---

This is just for the leader key, but if you want to extend to any kind of key I think you need to use `execute` anyway.

In the `normal` help:

```
An alternative is to use :execute, which uses a
expression as argument.  This allows the use of
printable characters to represent special characters.

Example:
    :exe "normal \<c-w>\<c-w>"
{not in Vi, of course}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! I made it a one-liner to avoid the use of the function: `command! -nargs=1 NormLead  execute "normal " . (get(g:,"mapleader","\\")==' ' ? "1" : get(g:,"mapleader","\\")) . <f-args>`: it is still not perfect (doesn't work with special keys or with combinations beginning with 2 leaders) but that's something

Comment: Nice, I'll add this to the answer

Comment: @statox, in my vimrc I have `let mapleader = "\<Space>"` and `nnoremap <leader>p  :pwd<CR>`; I've added the `command!` from your comment (or the one from the answer), and when I open Vim and try `:NormLead p`, I just get the effect of `p`utting. Any clues?

Comment: @Enlico I don't really have a clue no but you should definitely ask that in a new question (don't forget to include all the relevant code from your config in case it's a simple typo)

Comment: @statox, I asked in a comment first just to make sure I was not making some mistake which is obvious to you or the answerer. Now that I know that's not the case, I'll ask a question. Thanks ;)

Comment: @statox, [asked](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/42949/how-to-use-leader-in-a-normal-command-today) if you're interested.