# How to use <Leader> in a normal command today?

Tags: vimscript, key-bindings, command, leader

The answer to [the question with the same title](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7779/how-to-use-leader-in-a-normal-command) doesn't seem to work for me. Not sure if the behavior has just changed overtime.

To reproduce the issue, open Vim via `vim -Nu filebelow.vim`, where the first two lines are from my vimrc and the third line is from the linked answer and it should presumably allow prepending <kbd>Leader</kbd> to a key <kbd>a</kbd> in a normal command via `:NormLead a`.

```
let mapleader = "\<Space>"
nnoremap <leader>p  :pwd<CR>
command! -nargs=1 NormLead  let leader=get(g:,"mapleader","\\") | exec "normal " . (leader==' '?"1":leader).<f-args>
```

Unfortunately this solution just seems to result in <kbd>p</kbd>utting (whatever is the `"` register), and that's the case even if I use the `command` originally suggested in the comment by [statox](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/1841/statox).

Comment: I didn't give much thought about why you don't get the expected behavior but I feel like I should mention that `<leader>` is a placeholder that is expanded at the time of sourcing. This means that your `<leader>p` mapping is actually registered as `<Space>p` and that `g:mapleader` can be changed later on without changing previously registered `<leader>` mappings. In other words, querying `g:mapleader` only gives you *its current value*, which might not be the same as the one used when the mapping was created. Therefore, this strategy is too brittle.

Comment: You’ve eliminated the function but continued to use f-args… does it work if you actually use the full script from the linked question, or if you use q-args?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, that might apply to the update reported in the answer, but in the comment, statox writes what he says is a oneliner solution, so I expect that to have worked at some point in the past. Anyway, I'll give a shot to the full script later.

Comment: Oh, it’s not f- vs q-args, it’s the oneliner not replicating the logic correctly.  Try `(leader==' '?'1'.leader:leader)`

Comment: (If you referred to the oneliner in the answer and not that in the comment) Nope, it doesn't work: upon doing `:NormLead p` I get `E481: No range allowed`, because the attempted command line has become `:.pwd`.